# passing a function to another function within the same class

Tags: c++

I have a class named `DrawerApp` containing the functions
 `_genericLoadFromFile`, `Run`

I want to call each of the functions `_loadFromFileHelper`, `_loadFromBinHelper` from within the `Run` function, below:

```
void DrawerApp::Run()
{
    _genericLoadFromFile(_loadFromFileHelper);
    _genericLoadFromFile(_loadFromBinHelper);
}
```

And the `_genericLoadFromFile` looks like this:

```
bool DrawerApp::_genericLoadFromFile(static bool (DrawerApp::*helperFunc)(string)) 
{
/* do some stuff */
    string fileName = 'Test';
    success = (this->*helperFunc)(fileName);

}
```

but unfortunately I get the following error:

```
DrawerApp::_loadFromFileHelper': function call missing argument list; 
use '&DrawerApp::_loadFromFileHelper' to create a pointer to member
```

And also this warning:

```
Warning 1   warning C4042: 'helperFunc' : has bad storage class
```

How do I perform this properly? I don't get what I'm doing wrong.
Thank you

**Edit**

When I try to edit it as the error suggests to `&DrawerApp::_loadFromFileHelper` I get another errors:

```
Error   2   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "private: bool __thiscall DrawerApp::_loadFromFileHelper(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >)" (?_loadFromFileHelper@DrawerApp@@AAE_NV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z) referenced in function "private: void __thiscall DrawerApp::Run(void)" (?Run@DrawerApp@@AAEXXZ)
```

And

```
Error   3   error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

Comment: Consider using static polymorphism (templates) or plain old polymorphism instead.

Comment: Can you please give an example for the latter?

Comment: Is that first error really a linker error?  It looks more like a compiler error.

Comment: Edited, you're right. It isn't

Comment: Static function parameter? o.O what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Where is `DrawerApp::_loadFromFileHelper` defined?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was quite stupid. I didn't implement the methods correctly (forgot to put `DrawerApp::` in front of them.

Sorry for messing with your head :-)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the helper functions are declared static, there is no need to call them as member function pointers - they can just be called as ordinary function pointers, e.g. try this complete, compilable and linkable (though not very functional) example:

```
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class DrawerApp {
    public:

    void Run()
    {
        _genericLoadFromFile(_loadFromFileHelper);
        _genericLoadFromFile(_loadFromBinHelper);
    }

    static bool _loadFromFileHelper(string x) 
    {
        return true;
    }

    static bool _loadFromBinHelper(string x) 
    {
        return true;
    }

    bool _genericLoadFromFile(
            bool (*helperFunc)(string)) 
    {
        /* do some stuff */
        string fileName = "Test";
        bool success = (*helperFunc)(fileName);
        return success;
    }
};

int main () {
    DrawerApp a;
    a.Run();
    return 0;
}
```

This also shows that it is not necessary to show the storage class in the function definition for `_genericLoadFromFile()`.